# Stop a program within a function (python)

Tags: python, function, error-handling

I'm kinda new to coding and I'd like to be able to stop the program and if possible throw up a custom error message from within a function

(as in:

```
def Rounded_square(lots of inputs):
    radius = (calculation)
    if radius < 0:
        stop.program("The radius is negative")
```

)

Comment: Are you talking about exceptions?

Comment: Do you really mean stop or pause? Are you in a GUI environment or command line? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry I was just abstracting when i wrote the stop thing. Yeah it looks like exceptions were the way to go, thanks everyone (just using the basic spyder interface nothing fancy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *raise an exception*

```
raise ValueError("radius should be positive")
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough for this to be a definitive answer.

Comment: @PeterWood: probably, seems the most likely option however, and since the OP says he's new to coding, it's worth looking into exceptions

Answer (score 1):

To throw a custom error message you can do

```
raise BaseException("my exception text")
```

You can view built-in exception types [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

alternatively to exit the program you can just call

```
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`import os`
`os.exit("The radius is negative")` , the value inside the `exit()` function will be printed to `stderr` and the return code will be 1 (thanks to @peter-wood for that revelation)
and just before that you can just use `print` for the message

Comment: If anything other than an integer is passed to `exit`, Python converts it to a string, prints it to `stderr`, and exits with code `1`. See [**`sys.exit`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Comment: did not know that! , thank you , will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can throw exceptions using `raise` statement in python:

```
raise Exception('Message') # Exception: Message
```

It is also possible to create custom exceptions:

```
class MyException(Exception):
  pass

raise MyException('Message') # MyException: Message
```

So you should use:

```
raise TypeError('The radius is negative')
```

You should read some tutorials, about exceptions: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm